# Locating “Add Network Printer” 's exe location

Tags: c#

I was keen on using the Process class [C#] to open "Add Printer" wizard, but I was wondering what is the location of the wizard's exe? And if so, is there a way to open straight into the "Add a network, wireless or Bluetooth printer" section of the wizard?

I would be glad if someone can help.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do what you want by running a specific entry point in shell32.dll via rundll32.exe.  The one you want is AddPrinter.  For example;

```
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo {
    FileName = "rundll32.exe",
    CreateNoWindow = true,
    Arguments = "shell32.dll,SHHelpShortcuts_RunDLL AddPrinter",
    UseShellExecute = true
};
Process.Start(psi);
```

Answer (score 0):

From a console run `rundll32 printui.dll PrintUIEntry` for a help dialog describing available command RunDll command lines.

To launch the Install UI you need to execute `rundll32 printui.dll PrintUIEntry /il`

(`/ip` for a Network Printer)